# Logarithm Question- What is log 1 / by the square root of 10

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What is $\displaystyle \log \frac{1}{\sqrt{10}}$?

Thanks so much beforehand.

Comment: What base?  Shall we assume it is a natural logarithm?

Comment: Yes! One should assume that.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly $\ln (1/\sqrt{10})=\ln (\sqrt{1/10})=\frac{-1}{2} \ln 10$.  $\ln 10$ isn't a rational number, but rather $\ln 10 \approx 2.302585$.  Thus, $\ln (1/\sqrt{10})=-1.1512925$.

For the chance you wanted $\log_{10}$, we have all the same as the above, except now $\log_{10}(10)=1$, so that $\log_{10}(1/\sqrt{10})=-1/2$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\log\frac ab=\log a-\log b\implies \log\frac1{\sqrt{10}}=\log1-\log\sqrt{10}=-\frac12\log 10\;\;\text{(why?)}$$